# Separable Differential Equation explained

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So i have the equation dy/dt = 1+y

looking at the answers my lecture has given it states

d/dt(1+y) = 1 + y

then 1+y(t)=Ae^t where A is a constant

Can someone explain these steps please?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}(1+y) = \frac{d}{dt} 1 + \frac{dy}{dt} =0 + 1+y$ by the differential equation. replacing $x(t)=1+y(t)$ yields a differential equation for $x(t)$, which has as solution $x(t) = A e^t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $1$ is a constant,
$$\frac{d}{dt}(1+y)=\frac{d}{dt}(1)+\frac{d}{dt}(y)=0+\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}\ .$$
That's why your original DE can be written as
$$\frac{d}{dt}(1+y)=1+y\ .$$
Now this means that $1+y$ is a function which is equal to its own derivative.  What function could that be?  Basically it must be $e^t$, a function which equals its own derivative, but if you think about you will see that the same is true for any constant times $e^t$.  These are the only possibilities, so the solution is
$$1+y=Ae^t\ .$$

---

Adding $1$ is a neat trick, but might be confusing if you have not seen a lot of DEs.  If that is the case then you might do better to use the standard method:
$$\eqalign{\frac{dy}{dt}=1+y\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad \frac{1}{1+y}\frac{dy}{dt}=1\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad \int\frac{1}{1+y}\frac{dy}{dt}\,dt=\int 1\,dt\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad \int\frac{1}{1+y}\,dy=\int 1\,dt\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad \ln(1+y)=t+C\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad 1+y=e^{t+C}=e^Ce^t\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad 1+y=Ae^t\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this just as an answer I suppose:

$\frac{d}{dt}(1+y) = \frac{d}{dt} 1 + \frac{dy}{dt} =0 + (1+y)=1+y$ by the differential equation. Replacing $x(t)=1+y(t)$ yields a differential equation for $x(t)$, namely $\frac{dx}{dt} =x$, which has as solution $x(t) = A e^t$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the equation by separation of variables. Formally, you do this by multiplying $1+y$ and $dt$ (multiplying an "infinitesimal $dt$" might seem strange, but it is easy to remember the technique with it) and integrate on both sides:
$$\int_{y_0}^y \frac{1}{1+\eta}d\eta = \int_{t_0}^{t} 1 ds$$
From this, you get the equation
$$ \ln(1+y)-\ln(1+y_0) = t - t_0$$
and further:
$$ 1+y = (1+y_0) e^{t-t_0}$$
If you set $A := 1 + y_0$, you get the desired result (of course in your case, $t_0=0$).